# Imputing data with mice gives me an undescriptive error

Tags: r

The following is a snippet of my code. I am trying to impute a binary variable (I'll call it `variable`) based on the rest of the variables in the dataset.

When I run mice I get the following error:

> Error: (converted from warning) Number of logged events: 2

Even if I run mice with maxit = 0

```
n<-nrow(mydata).  # dataset with all complete cases will remove some obstacles in variable, which is a binary 0-1 variable

samples <- sample(1:n, p*n, FALSE)
ampfile<-mydata
ampfile$variable[samples]<-NA
    

mice(ampfile, maxit = 5, m = 10,method="pmm",seed = 1)
```

as well as

```
mice(ampfile, maxit = 0)
```

both gave the error:

> Error: (converted from warning) Number of logged events: 2

I looked online but I can't find any answer that relates to this problem.

Comment: [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448882/mice-imputation-troubleshooting-in-r-with-categorical-variables) suggests that the warning occurs when variables are not of type factor. What does `str(ampfile)` show?